# mybatis mapper on node express xml regular expression error

Tags: node.js, xml, express, mybatis-mapper

when I open the web page via node express + mybatis-mapper,
it works on dev environment on my PC(windows + vscode).
But it not works on linux(ubuntu) server with below error message.

It seems like xml encoding error, but I can't find the way to solve.
(ex. special character & -> /amp )

please help me find the way..

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^([\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]+)/: Invalid escape
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at Object.createWordRegex (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/regexFactory.js:38:10)
    at new Tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Tokenizer.js:74:36)
    at StandardSqlFormatter.tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/languages/StandardSqlFormatter.js:57:14)
    at StandardSqlFormatter.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Formatter.js:87:26)
    at Object.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/sqlFormatter.js:74:29)
    at MybatisMapper.getStatement (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/mybatis-mapper/index.js:109:32)
    at router.get (/home/minieyes85/routes/main.js:51:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
```

checked preference setting of vscode text-editor encoding -> utf-8

open the web page without error

Answer (score 0):

yes because syntax error
at new RegExp ()
at Object.createWordRegex (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/regexFactory.js:38:10)
at new Tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Tokenizer.js:74:36)
at StandardSqlFormatter.tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/languages/StandardSqlFormatter.js:57:14)
at StandardSqlFormatter.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Formatter.js:87:26)
at Object.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/sqlFormatter.js:74:29)
at MybatisMapper.getStatement

Comment: How can I solve this error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

yes because syntax error at new RegExp () at Object.createWordRegex (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/regexFactory.js:38:10) at new Tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Tokenizer.js:74:36) at StandardSqlFormatter.tokenizer (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/languages/StandardSqlFormatter.js:57:14) at StandardSqlFormatter.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/core/Formatter.js:87:26) at Object.format (/home/minieyes85/node_modules/sql-formatter/lib/sqlFormatter.js:74:29) at MybatisMapper.getStatement

Comment: How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const mybatisMapper = require('mybatis-mapper');

// create the connection to database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'test'
});
    
// create the myBatisMapper from xml file
mybatisMapper.createMapper([ './fruits.xml' ]);
    
// SQL Parameters
var param = {
    category : 'apple',
    price : 100
}
    
// Get SQL Statement
var format = {language: 'sql', indent: '  '};
var query = mybatisMapper.getStatement('fruit', 'testBasic', param, format);
    
// Do it!
connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results); 
    console.log(fields);
});
```

in above code, var format <- this variable is problem in ubuntu,
so I deleted var format and write code as like `mybatisMapper.getStatement("","",param)` without foramt.